# Fomatação de Date no TXT para comparar com o Date do Banco de Dados

Tags: delphi

Segue o código:

```
dtcompra := copy(lTemp,65,2)+'-'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'-'+copy(lTemp,58,4);
if
DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtcompra').AsDateTime = StrToDateTime(dtcompra)
then
begin
//codigo
end;
```

Alguma dica de melhorar o código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu prefiro proteger os dados para evitar exceções inesperadas, então eu faria assim:

```
//Pega a data do arquivo texto
dtCompraTxt := copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,58,4);

//Tenta converter a data em texto para tipo TDateTime, se não conseguir lança exceção
if not TryStrToDateTime(dtCompraTxt, dtCompra) then
  raise EConvertError.CreateFmt('A data do arquivo ("%s") não é uma data válida.', [dtCompraTxt]);

//Realiza a comparação das datas com SameDate da unit DateUtils
if SameDate(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtcompra').AsDateTime, dtCompra) then
begin

end;
```

Documentação sobre SameDate neste **[link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.DateUtils.SameDate)**

*Obs.: Assim será comparada somente data e não hora minutos e segundos*

Comment: Tem uma forma mais simples e fazê-la, para eu entender direitinho como funciona a função do sql e do delphi.

Comment: Adicionei alguns comentários, não sei se é o q queria

Answer (score 0):

o problema nessa abordagem é que as configurações regionais do sistema operacional do seu usuário, podem não corresponder ao formato da string que você tem no TXT.

Por exemplo:

Se sua string de data for: **01-12-2014** **(1 de Dezembro)** e o windows do usuário estiver configurado para o inglês, a data será interpretada como sendo **"12 de Janeiro"**.

Para evitar esse problema, utilize o método [StrToDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.StrToDateTime), passando [TFormatSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings)

```
var
  AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
  dtcompra  : TDateTime;
begin
   AFormatSettings:=TFormatSettings.Create;
   AFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:='dd-mm-yyyy';
   AFormatSettings.DateSeparator:='-';
   dtcompra  :=  StrToDateTime('01-12-2014', AFormatSettings);
```